# function keeps returning true, should return false

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my function i keep getting my error message (please select an option before proceeding) but then it returns true, not false. thanks for any help!

```
function validateaccessories()
{
var solocups = window.document.getElementById("cups").value;
var bags = window.document.getElementById("bags").value;
var coal = window.document.getElementById("coal").value;

if(solocups == "color" && bags == "set" && coal == "size")
    {
    alert("Please select an option before proceeding");
    return false;
    }

return true;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think returns true? How are you checking it?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code, it will return false, so how are using/calling it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if I run the code so that I see the alert, the function will return false.

Comment: im calling it through onsubmit in my html code, still returning false for me.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using this as a form validation handler and the form is still submitting, see my answer below. If correct, please mark as answered, otherwise please edit your question to better email it. Thanks and Welcome!

Comment: *"...still returning false for me"*. So which is it? Your question says it's returning true, and your comment says false. If the `alert()` shows, then it is not returning `true`. You may be convinced that it is, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's the way you are calling it.

You want `onSubmit="return validateaccessories();"`

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the code is that you have an if. Somehow it doesn't stop at return false. What you could do is make it an if/else statement so that it's allways one or the other.